# What's the technique to do expand/compact stack on iPad like Reeder and Photos?

Tags: ipad, ios, animation

On iPad, both the native Photos app as well as Reeder use a "expand/collapse stack" technique. Initially there is a stack of items on top of one another, each angled a bit with different corners showing. When you interact with them, the stack expands into a full screen and the items are laid out in a grid. When you collapse them, they collapse back into a stack.

What's the best way to set up my views to do the same thing? Should I just have a bunch of UIviews (one for each item) and manipulate their coordinates/transforms with an animation, or is there something more to it? Any example apps with code?

(Note: I am not asking about the interaction to invoke expand/collapse, I'm only asking what's the most appropriate way to lay out and set up my items.)

Comment: Hows your progress on this going? I'm about to role my own implementation as well for a project and I'm looking for the same kind of help you are asking for.

Comment: I actually did not find an answer from elsewhere, so I did my own implementation which works quite fine. I should get off my ass and post it as an example project.

Comment: Hello Jaanus,

I saw you mention that you figured this out and you were thinking of posting an example of your implementation.  I'm just curious if you ever got around to doing that, as I am very interested on how you accomplished this, I would love to play around with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days, use UICollectionView with different layouts and transitioning between layouts.